# Is SegWit similar to/ derived from Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: segregated-witness

Segregating the witness (signature) data from the transactional data is similar to the structure used in Hyperledger Fabric.
Curious about the derivation of SegWit?

Comment: I know almost nothing about Hyperledger, but maybe this helps writing an answer: Segregated Witness (on a Bitcoin-like system) was first deployed in Elements Alpha, released in May 2015, while the Hyperledger project only started in December 2015. It's also a very straightforward design (and arguably Bitcoin's legacy one was the weird one), several from scratch projects never considered anything else

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. It clears out everthing.

Answer (score 1):

OP clearly felt his question was adequately answered by Pieter Wuille's comment:

> Segregated Witness (on a Bitcoin-like system) was first deployed in Elements Alpha, released in May 2015, while the Hyperledger project only started in December 2015. It's also a very straightforward design (and arguably Bitcoin's legacy one was the weird one), several from scratch projects never considered anything else

---

> **Is SegWit derived from Hyperledger Fabric?**

No, the dates above make this very unlikely.